# Tabulator, vue.js - how to set focus of a cell after table refeshData

Tags: vue.js, tabulator

Using Tablulator (great product!), I am trying to keep the cursor from resetting to the first editable cell in the table after editing a cell. The `replaceData` function is updating the data element, and while the scroll position does not change, the cursor is reset. I'm not sure how to do this correctly. The documentation, while great, is silent about cursor position beyond the `next()`, etc methods, which I cannot quite get to work.

In my vue.js table definition component, I have a `watch` like this:

```
watch: {
            tableData: {
                handler: function (newData) {
                    this.tabulator.replaceData(newData);
                },
                deep: true,
            }
        },
```

and a cellEdited method inside `mounted` like this:

```
mounted() {
            let self = this;
            //todo Possibly validate that cater tips is less than total tips since cater tips is a portion of total tips
            self.tabulator = new Tabulator(self.$refs.myTable, {
                height: 380, // set height of table (in CSS or here)
                placeholder: 'Click "Load Store Tips" to edit data',
                data: self.tableData, //link data to table
                reactiveData: true, //enable data reactivity
                downloadConfig: {columnCalcs: false},
                addRowPos:"bottom",          
                history:true,             
                layout: "fitDataFill", 
                initialSort:[             
                    {column:"storeID", dir:"asc"},
                 ],
                //Define Table Columns
                columns: [
                    {title: "Store ID", field: "storeID", sorter:"number"},
                    {title: "Store Tips", field: "inStore_tips", align: "right", formatter: "money",  editor: "number", bottomCalc: "sum"},
                    {title: "Cater Tips", field: "cater_tips", align: "right", formatter: "money", editor: "number", bottomCalc: "sum"},
                    {title: "Client ID", field: "clientID"},
                ],
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                // When a cell is edited, write the data out to the server to ensure it is
                // always in a saved state.
                ////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
                cellEdited: function (e, cell) {
                    //self.colPos = cell.getColumn(); //trying to save the cursor pos, but generating error
                    //self.rowPos = cell.getRow(); // generating error
                    self.PostTipsEventMethod();

                }
            });
```

Here is what I have tried:

- Tried capturing the row and column position, and then setting that after the `replaceData` table render, and after the `cellEdited` method
- Tried using the next() method to move the cursor to the next cell inside the `cellEdited` method, before and after the `replaceData` function.

Can someone guide me a bit further on this? I've searched through the tabulator element in the debugger trying to find the row and column numbers of the cell I'm editing, but so far, no joy. I guess I don't understand the lifecycle of the table rendering well enough.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you have to use replaceData?  I think that if you just update an individual cell, then you won't have an issue.  For example, make your post request against your server inside of the cellEdited.  If the response accepts the value, then you don't need to do anything else.  If the response does not accept the value, then you need to just reset the single cell.  (Also, cellEdited takes a single parameter of cell.  It does not have an event parameter.)

Comment: I will try it without the replaceData - I kind of assumed that was necessary for the table to be built in the beginning, but since the table gets built via the mounted method, I see that my assumption is false. And, good catch on the 1 cellEdited parameter. I missed that, though I don't think I need that now.

Comment: If you still have issues, I can create an example for you.  It will be just regular JavaScript though, without Vue.  The concept will be the same though.

Comment: Yes, if I add a method ```displayTable()``` in the child component that calls ```replaceData()``` instead of in the watch{}, and call that method in the parent of the table constructor via ```this.$refs.tableRef.displayTable(this.storeTipsTableData);``` (I use a button click to load the data, so the call is done in that method), it does work and it does update the table. It is a bit more of a manual lift to display the table but it certainly fixes my issue without having to mess with the position of the active cursor. Please post this as an answer.

Comment: Any clue why I cannot refer to the this.tableData in the child instead of needing to pass the data into the child via parameter like this: ```displayTable: function(newData) {
                this.tabulator.replaceData(newData);
            },```   tableData is a prop in the child.

Comment: I would need to see all of the relevant pieces of the component to say for sure.  Chances are it is just something to do with the context and how you are binding the function.  If you call `console.log(this)` inside of the `displayTable` function, you should be able to see what `this` actually refers to.  From there, you should be able to investigate the issue further.  You may need to call `displayTable` and pass the context of what `this` is by using `bind` or `call`.

Comment: @nrayburn-tech, very good. Thanks for the help.